# Why the error in this simple template code?

Tags: c++, templates

Why does the error occur below?

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename FooType>
struct bar {
  using bar_type = typename FooType::foo_type;
};

template<typename T>
struct foo {
  using foo_type = T;

  //Error: No type named 'bar_type' in 'bar<foo<int> >'
  static_assert(std::is_same<foo_type,typename bar<foo<T>>::bar_type>::value,"");
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  bar<foo<int>> b;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17478621/420683)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the point of the `static_assert`, `foo` isn't yet a complete type (you're still within its definition), so when `bar` tries to reach in, the compiler gives you an error. The particular error it gives you sucks though; try it with a different compiler.

Comment: As Johannes Schaub pointed out in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17497838/420683) to the question I linked in the comment to the OP, it might even be *not explicitly specified* by the Standard.whether it is illegal or not.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. I just looked at the code, thought about Clang's instantiation model, and described the issue I saw.