# Accessing inner class in CRTP (in C++)

Tags: c++, inner-classes, crtp

The following minimal example does not compile.

```
template<class T>
class Base1 {};

template<class Impl>
class Base2 : public Base1<typename Impl::Inner> {}; // line 5

struct C : public Base2<C> // line 7
{
    class Inner;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    (void)c;
    return 0;
}
```

The error:

```
> g++ -std=c++11 -Wall incomplete.cpp -o incomplete
incomplete.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class Base2<C>’:
incomplete.cpp:7:19:   required from here
incomplete.cpp:5:7: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct C’
incomplete.cpp:7:8: error: forward declaration of ‘struct C’
```

Now, however, replacing the code for Base2 with this works:

```
template<class Impl>
class Base2
{
    struct BaseInner : public Base1<typename Impl::Inner> {};
};
```

Why (exactly) does the error not occur now? Can I get rid of the error in the first code example?

Note: The following code works of course, but has the disadvantage that I will need to inherit twice every time I want to construct a class like C. I wish there was a solution where everything is done before giving Base2 a template.

```
template<class Impl>
class Base2
{
    struct BaseInner : public Base1<typename Impl::Inner> {};
};

struct _C : public Base2<_C> // line 7
{
    class Inner {};
};

struct C : public _C, _C::Inner
{
};
```

Comment: `class Inner;` is declared on line 9, but you're referencing it on line 7.

Comment: @Adam could we make Inner a template and instantiate (i.e. declare) it later?

Comment: instantiate != declare. I don't see a way out of this circular dependency other than your Base2 scheme. But I also don't see what you're trying to accomplish. What do you want to do that you can't do with vanilla CRTP?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/17478621/420683

Comment: Even with the solution of Base2's BaseInner, cpp only declares the struct BaseInner, but cannot initiate a Base2 member `BaseInner baseInner;`, which will still through an error. I guess this is related to how compiler decides to expanse the template at different time