# How to get subtype of a derived class in base class

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following example

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
        typename T::x a;          //not used
        virtual typename T::x* function()=0;
};

class B:public A<B>
{
public:
        typedef XXX x;
        x obj;
        x* function()
        {
             return &obj;
        }

};
```

Here I want to use the the type `B::x` inside class `A`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Dont you do this already?

Comment: Getting error `invalid use of undefined type `class B`

Comment: Isn't this problem very similar to the one discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17478621/420683)?

Comment: @dyp It's similar, but in this case due to the class in question being the parent class, there are even more restrictions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't work. In order to instantiate `A`, the compiler needs to have at least a forward declaration of `x`. But you cannot forward declare members of a type as this is an implementation detail of the type and would imply that you already know some parts about the class.

You could, however, try to pass the return type directly to `A` and use this as the return type:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    typedef T ret_type;
    virtual ret_type* function() = 0;
};

class B : public A<int>
{
public:
    A::ret_type obj;
    virtual A::ret_type* function() override
    {
         return &obj;
    }
};
```

With this approach you could do this:

```
class X : public A<int> { ... };
class Y : public A<int> { ... };

A<int>* p1 = new X();
A<int>* p2 = new Y();
p1->function();
p2->function();
```

...making the baseclass much more useful.

A parent should not need to know anything about its children, otherwise inheritance becomes meaningless. In your case `A` can be considered an interface and it makes sense that any class implementing the interface `A<int>` will behave the same. Contrary, if you pass the child-class to `A`, every interface implementation is different and unique, even though it might have exactly the same return types. If you really need this, consider making `A` a utility class and embedding it inside the subclass as a member ("favor composition over inheritance").

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I think i can achieve the desire result by using this concept.