# Curiously Recurring Template and Template parameter dependent subclassing issues

Tags: c++, templates, subclassing, crtp

I am trying to make the following code work

```
template < class __derived, class __object = typename __derived::Object >
struct Base {
    using Derived = __derived;
    using Object = __object;
    void function(Object o) { return Derived::function(s); }
}

//template < class __derived >
//struct Base {
//    using Derived = __derived;
//    using Object = typename Derived::Object;
//    void function(Object o) { return Derived::function(s); }
//}

template < class __object >
struct Derived : public Base< Derived< __Object > > {
    using Object = __object;
    void function(Object o) { ... }
}
```

And i instantiate an object by declaring

```
Derived<double> obj;
```

Problem is, the compiler claims not to be able to find the symbol `Object` inside the `Derived` class while deducing the second template parameter for the `Base` class. The same error is also generated by the commented version.

I am trying to do this under inspiration of Eigen3 code, particularly the CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern) they use in order to avoid use of virtual functions. Eigen3 actually uses a `traits` class but I can't figure out how to imitate that for the present case.
Anyone has any suggestion about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Derived can't instantiate `Object` until after `Base` is instantiated, but `Base` can't instantiate since `Derived::Object` doesn't exist yet.  Yeah, use a traits class.

Comment: Please don't use identifiers with a double underscore. Those are reserved for the C++ implementation (compiler/library).

Comment: What is this? The C++ version of Inception?

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/q/17478621/420683

Comment: @Praetorian I think it's the IRTIP. The infinitely recurring template instantiation pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, if you want A to inherit from B, then B cannot know anything about A other than it's declaration:

```
template < class __object >
struct Derived;
```

Unfortunately, you want to get more, so you'll have to use a type trait:

```
template<class __derived>
struct Base_traits {
    //using Object = ?????;
};
template<class __object>
struct Base_traits<Derived<__object>> {
    using Object = __object; //note, this also can't inspect B.
};
```

The `Base` class can inspect the `Base_traits` all it wants, because the traits don't inspect `B` at all.

```
template < class __derived, class __object = typename Base_traits<__derived>::Object >
struct Base {
    using Derived = __derived;
    using Object = typename Base_traits<__derived>::Object;
    //or        
    using Object = __object;
```

---

Unrelated, leading double underscores are disallowed for use by mortals, use a single leading underscore followed by a lowercase letter.  Alternatively, use a trailing underscore.

Also, the syntax

```
void function(Object o) { return Derived::function(s); }
```

Won't work, because that notation cannot be used for upcasts, only downcasts.  Ergo, you have to use `static_cast` on the `this`.  Since that's vaguely ugly, I put it behind a function:

```
    void foo(Object o) { self()->bar(o); }
private:
    __derived* self() {return static_cast<__derived*>(this);}
    const __derived* self() const {return static_cast<__derived*>(this);}
};
```

Full code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81595b0fcd36ab93

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I managed to get it work! Now I'm focusing on another problem which is unrelated, so I will post another question! Thanks!