# C++ macro that inserts typename if necessary

Tags: c++, templates, macros, typename

I have a macro for auto-subtyping of a template with inheriting constructors which looks like this:

```
#define INST_TMPL(NAME,TMPL,...)  \
struct NAME : public TMPL<__VA_ARGS__> {    \
   typedef TMPL<__VA_ARGS__> Base;\
   using Base::Base;\ // Inherit constructors
};
```

Please no arguments whether such a macro is necessary or good style. It is very helpful in our project; we use it to shorten type names of very long templates. For example, we can shorten the name of a template `LongName<int,float,x::y::LongInnerType>` by using `INST_TMPL(MyType,LongName,int,float,x::y::LongInnerType)`. Now we can simply use `MyType` instead of the long template and the type will also be displayed in error messages (instead of the expanded template name).

But now there is one Problem: Depending on the template used, we sometimes need a `typename` in the `typedef` inside the macro. For example, if the used template is an inner template of a template parameter `T`, e.g.`T::LongName<...>`, then we would need the `typename` in  the typedef, i.e.:

```
   typedef typename TMPL<__VA_ARGS__> Base;\
```

Of course, I could create two macros, one with the `typename` and one without. However, that is quite cumbersome. Instead, I would like to have a macro that always compiles correctly for both scenarios. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not: `template <template <typename...> class Tmpl, typename ...Args> struct Wrap : Tmpl<Args...> { using base = Tmpl<Args...>; using base::base; };` [Example](http://ideone.com/nimVZ8)

Comment: Where you now write `T::LongName`, why can you not simply pass `typename T::LongName` as your macro argument?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Now try inserting `Tmpl = a::B`, your `using` will end up like this: `using a::B<...>::a::B<...>` which does not compile.

Comment: @hvd: This does not work in the inheritance, I receive the error: `keyword ‘typename’ not allowed in this context (the base class is implicitly a type)`

Comment: @KerrekSB: The problem is not the template. The problem is that you are using a qualified name as constructor name which just doesn't work. The constructor of class `a::B` is `a::B::B`, not `a::B::a::B`.

Comment: @gexicide: I changed that to use an intermediate type alias.

Comment: @gexicide Ah, sorry, missed that. You could work around that by defining a typedef outside of your current class definition, and then using that typedef as the base class (so you'd get `typedef typename T::LongName<...> NAMEBase; struct NAME : public NAMEBase { typedef NAMEBase Base; using Base::Base; };`), but that's not exactly pretty.

Comment: @hvd: I did this. But the problem is that some of the usages of the macro are to instanciate a curiously recurring template, i.e., `struct A : public B<A>`. I cannot `typedef` a curiously recurring template before the struct itself, since `A` will not be declared, yet.

Comment: Can you post a test case, so we can try different approaches on it?

Comment: Why don't you just only have the `typename` version? It's perfectly legal.

Comment: @gexicide How about simplifying it a lot? `#define INST_TMPL(NAME,TYPENAME,...) struct NAME : __VA_ARGS__ { typedef TYPENAME __VA_ARGS__ Base; using Base::Base; };` It could be used like `INST_IMPL(MyType,,LongName<int,float,x::y::LongInnerType>)`, or like `INST_IMPL(MyType,typename,T::LongName<int,float,x::y::LongInnerType>)`?

Comment: @hvd: I also thought about this one, i.e., having an extra parameter for the `typename`, but it looks so ugly having the `,,` in there when not using `typename`. But maybe if I forward declare the struct, then typedef, then instanciate, I could use your second suggestion even on curiously recurring templates.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode No, it's not. The rules for `typename` are less strict than they used to be, but there are still a lot of cases where `typename` is simply not allowed and not accepted by compilers.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: I am afraid but it is not legal, if I use `typename` on a simple type, I get the error: `error: expected nested-name-specifier`

Comment: does this helps ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274941/curiously-recurring-template-and-template-parameter-dependent-subclassing-issues

Comment: @gexicide Okay, one last idea: `template <typename T> struct id { typedef T type; }; #define INST_TMPL(NAME,...) struct NAME : id<__VA_ARGS__>::type { typedef typename id<__VA_ARGS__>::type Base; using Base::Base; };`. Use it like `INST_IMPL(MyType,LongName<int,float,x::y::LongInnerType>)`, or like `INST_IMPL(MyType,typename T::LongName<int,float,x::y::LongInnerType>)`? Here, the inner `typename` is allowed even when it isn't required.

Comment: @hvd: Works like a charm. Post as answer to receive the well-earned reputation :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments:

A way to rewrite this where `typename` can be specified through the macro arguments is to use a helper template class that simply reports its own template argument.

```
template <typename T>
struct id { typedef T type; };

#define INST_TMPL(NAME,...) \
  struct NAME : id<__VA_ARGS__>::type { \
    typedef typename id<__VA_ARGS__>::type Base; \
    using Base::Base; \
  };
```

Use it like `INST_IMPL(MyType,LongName<int,float,x::y::LongInnerType>)`, or like `INST_IMPL(MyType,typename T::LongName<int,float,x::y::LongInnerType>)`.

The use of `typename id<...>::type` is allowed even if this is a non-dependent type.

Comment: isn't this equivalent to a type_trait from the standard ?

Comment: @user2485710 I think you're thinking of `std::identity<T>`. That was dropped from the standard because of compatibility issues and because code can easily define it itself if it needs it.

Comment: @hvd: That's `std::common_type_t<T>` (or `std::common_type<T>::type`, if you're a Neanderthal).

Comment: @KerrekSB Ah, you're right that it would always work here for correct uses as `T` is known to be a class type, but `std::common_type_t<T>` isn't generally `T`: using that would allow `INST_IMPL(MyType,BaseClass&)`, and I think it makes more sense for that to be an error as it is with my `id` structure.