# Point of instantiation of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, instantiation, token-name-resolution

Could that code to be compile?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct TMPL
{
    using TP = typename T::TP; //is CL::TP visible (with T == CL)?
};

struct CL
{
    using TP = int;
    TMPL<CL>::TP val; 
};

int main()
{
    CL cl;
}
```

TMPL is instantiated immediately before CL class definition according to Standard 14.6.4.1/4

> For a class template specialization, ..., if the specialization is
>   implicitly instantiated because it is referenced from within another
>   template specialization, .... **Otherwise, the point of instantiation
>   for such a specialization immediately precedes the namespace scope
>   declaration or definition that refers to the specialization.**

So, CL::TP isn't visible in TMPL instantiation point, but all the compilers (MSVC, gcc, clang) compile it fine. I also has found a defect report http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#287, but it, apparently, wasn't accepted

Comment: Also, it wasn't "rejected". It's "drafting". If it was "rejected", the status would be NAD.

Comment: I has read it, but that proposal isn't accepted yet, and code in my sample shouldn't be compile, as I think

Comment: As I said, `CL` is not a template. The defect doesn't apply to it. The intent of the defect is to make the case where `CL` *is* a template the same as your code example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478621/when-instantiating-a-template-should-members-of-its-incomplete-argument-types-b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is not identical to the one in the [defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#287). In the defect report, `CL` is a class template. However the intent of  the proposed resolution is to make the template case the same as the non-template one, aka [[basic.scope.pdecl]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.pdecl):

> 6 After the point of declaration of a class member, the member name
>   can be looked up in the scope of its class. [ *Note:* this is true
>   even if the class is an incomplete class. For example,
>
> ```
> struct X {
>   enum E { z = 16 };
>   int b[X::z];      // OK
> };
> ```
>
> — *end note* ]

Then the proposed resolution:

> In 14.6.4.1 [temp.point] paragraph 3 change:
>
> the point of instantiation is immediately before the point of
>   instantiation of the enclosing template. Otherwise, the point of
>   instantiation for such a specialization immediately precedes the
>   namespace scope declaration or definition that refers to the
>   specialization.
>
> To:
>
> the point of instantiation is **the same** as the point of
>   instantiation of the enclosing template. Otherwise, the point of
>   instantiation for such a specialization immediately precedes the
>   **nearest enclosing declaration. [Note: The point of instantiation is still at namespace scope but any declarations preceding the point of
>   instantiation, even if not at namespace scope, are considered to have
>   been seen.]**
>
> Add following paragraph 3:
>
> If an implicitly instantiated class template specialization, class
>   member specialization, or specialization of a class template
>   references a class, class template specialization, class member
>   specialization, or specialization of a class template containing a
>   specialization reference that directly or indirectly caused the
>   instantiation, the requirements of completeness and ordering of the
>   class reference are applied in the context of the specialization
>   reference.

As of the latest [draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.point#4), the non-template case was and is still valid. The template case is not. However the defect is [drafting](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#Issue%20Status), which means that the template case is intended to compile.

> **Drafting:** Informal consensus has been reached in the working group and is described in rough terms in a Tentative Resolution, although
>   precise wording for the change is not yet available.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I just meant a non-template case, where point of instantiation is placed before CL class and can't see members of CL, which are placed later